# jquery-ui scrollbar background looks odd

Tags: jquery-ui

[Here](http://stellarknowledge.com/) is a page I'm working on. I'm only targeting css3 at the moment. It may work with css2 but will look odd.

The scrollbar on the bottom right, why does it start out light and then go dark? I would have expected it to stay light like the bottom left scrollbar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the background image from `.ui-widget-content`. The image in question is `ui-bg_gloss-wave_20_111111_500x100.png` and that's a 500x100 PNG that's light on top and dark on the bottom. The horizontal scroll bar only uses the top bit of it so it ends up being a solid color, the vertical one ends up using a thin vertical slice so you get the odd coloring that you're seeing.

Comment: So the theme that jquery provided is mucked up on horizontal scrollbars :-/  Is there a way to fix with with just CSS?

Comment: I'd make a background image adjustment for `.ui-slider-vertical` to make the problem go away. If you look at the jQuery-UI demos for vertical sliders you'll notice that they're using a 100px tall subtle gradient and their vertical slider isn't that tall so maybe no one has ever noticed the problem.

Comment: Cheers. The jQuery-UI CSS is rather complex, Chrome's DOM inspector is invaluable when trying to figure it out.